# Show only filters in layered navigation for search results where all products have that filter populated

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, search

I am trying to implement this feature:
the filters that are shown in the search results page are only visible if every products in that results page have the attribute linked with the filter populated.

For instance, a search result have 2 products:

- product A with attribute Attribute1 and Attribute2 both populated
- Product B with only the Attribute1 populated

I would like that the filter shown in the search result is only the filter of the Attribute1 (because the product B doesn't have the Attribute2 populated).

I already did this with the layered navigation on categories,
by modifying the following file:

> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtm

in the following way:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 */
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
?>



<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()) : ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="block-title filter-title">
            <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shop By')) ?></strong>
        </div>

        <div class="block-content filter-content">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>

            <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()) : ?>
                <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getClearUrl()) ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear All')) ?></span></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter) : ?>
                <?php if (!$wrapOptions) : ?>
                    <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shopping Options')) ?></strong>
                    <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
                    <?php $wrapOptions = true;
                endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()>1) : ?>

<?php  if($filter->getName() != __('Category')) : ?>

        <?php if ($category->getProductCollection()->count() == $category->getProductCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('sku') ->addAttributeToFilter($block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getRequestVar())),array('notnull'=>true))->getSize()) : ?>
                        <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                        <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php  else: ?>

        <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                        <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if ($wrapOptions) : ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I cannot do the same with the search result.
Can please somebody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
below the code:

```
  1 <?php
  2 /**
  3  * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
  4  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  5  */
  6 ?>
  7 <?php
  8 /**
  9  * Category layered navigation
 10  *
 11  * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 12  */
 13 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 14 $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
 15 
 16 $layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
 17 
 18 ?>
 19 
 20 
 21 
 22 <?php if ($block->canShowBlock()) : ?>
 23     <div class="block filter">
 24         <div class="block-title filter-title">
 25             <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shop By')) ?></strong>
 26         </div>
 27 
 28         <div class="block-content filter-content">
 29             <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>
 30 
 31             <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()) : ?>
 32                 <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
 33                     <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getClearUrl()) ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear All')) ?></span></a>
 34                 </div>
 35             <?php endif; ?>
 36             <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
 37             <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter) : ?>
 38                 <?php if (!$wrapOptions) : ?>
 39                     <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Shopping Options')) ?></strong>
 40                     <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
 41                     <?php $wrapOptions = true;
 42                 endif; ?>
 43                     <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()>1) : ?>
 44 
 45 <?php  if($filter->getName() != __('Category')) : ?>
 46 
 47 <?php if ($category) : ?>
 48 
 49         <?php if ($category->getProductCollection()->count() == $category->getProductCollection() ->addAttributeToSelect('sku') ->addAttributeToFilter($block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getRequestVar())),array('notnull'=>true))->getSize()) : ?>
 50                         <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
 51                         <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
 52     <?php endif; ?>
 53 
 54 <?php else: ?>
 55 
 56 <?php
 57 
 58 echo "ciao";
 59 $prodottiora = $block->getResultCount();
 60 echo $prodottiora;
 61 
 62 echo $block->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->count();
 63 
 64 
 65 echo $block->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter($block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getRequestVar())),array('notnull'=>true))->getSize();
 66 
 67 ?>
 68 
 69 <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->count() == $block->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('sku')->addAttributeToFilter($block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getRequestVar())),array('notnull'=>true))->getSize()) : ?>
 70                         <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
 71                         <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
 72     <?php endif; ?>
 73 
 74 
 75 
 76 
 77 
 78 
 79 <?php endif; ?>
 80 
 81 <?php  else: ?>
 82 
 83 
 84         <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
 85                         <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
 86 <?php endif; ?>
 87 <?php endif; ?>
 88             <?php endforeach; ?>
 89             <?php if ($wrapOptions) : ?>
 90                 </dl>
 91             <?php endif; ?>
 92         </div>
 93     </div>
 94 <?php endif; ?>
```